# How to call Event trigger on each text box focus event in mvvm application

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am working on a Touch screen application in which I need to open touch screen key board when  cursor focuses on any textbox. I am using the following code to call my command which is in  view model..

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding openKeyboard}" />
   </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

It is working fine when I wrote on each textbox... Let I have multiple text boxes in single form, Is there any way to write it commonly and should be apply for all my textboxes of my form (or) application?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use attached behaviors.  Here is an example of one I have for selecting the value in a text box when it gains focus.  This way you can apply this behavior to any textbox.  One of the great things about attached behaviors is many properties/events are at the UIElement level so you can reuse some behaviors accross multiple controls.  Anyhow, here is my example:

**Behavior**

```
 public class SelectAllOnFocusedBehavior
{

    private static bool GetSelectAllOnFocused(TextBox textBox)
    {
        return (bool) textBox.GetValue(SelectAllOnFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectAllOnFocused(
        TextBox textBox, bool value)
    {
        textBox.SetValue(SelectAllOnFocusedProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectAllOnFocusedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "SelectAllOnFocused",
            typeof (bool),
            typeof (SelectAllOnFocusedBehavior),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnSelectAllOnFocusedChanged));

    private static void OnSelectAllOnFocusedChanged(
        DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox item = depObj as TextBox;
        if (item == null)
            return;
        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool) e.NewValue)
        {
            item.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += item_IgnoreLeftMouseDown;
            item.GotFocus+=item_GotFocus;
        }
        else
        {
            //remove EventsHere
            item.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= item_IgnoreLeftMouseDown;
            item.GotFocus -= item_GotFocus;
        }


    }

    static void item_IgnoreLeftMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Find the TextBox
        DependencyObject parent = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        while (parent != null && !(parent is TextBox))
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)parent;
            if (!textBox.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
            {
                // If the text box is not yet focussed, give it the focus and
                // stop further processing of this click event.
                textBox.Focus();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    static void  item_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         var item = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
         if (item != null)
            item.SelectAll();
    }


    //EventHandler Here

}
```

**Corresponding wpf**

```
 <TextBox x:Name="blahblah"  
                                 cmds:SelectAllOnFocusedBehavior.SelectAllOnFocused="True"
                                 cmds:NextTabItemOnEnterBehavior.NextTabItemOnEnter="True"
                                 Height="20" Width="75"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Caliburn you can do the following to trigger something on your ViewModel:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="openKeyboard" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And then create a method on your ViewModel with same name as your *MethodName*:

```cs
public void openKeyboard()
{
    // Do your stuff
}
```

I hope it helps.